# excel date filter - date picker "equal" is not working but "before" and "after" is working

Tags: excel, date

I want to filter a date in Excel worksheet using "Equals" and date picker.

Example:
 I want to filter a date which is 6 April 2022.
The filter work if I use the selection (tick) from the criteria list:
[image]

But when I tried to use the the menu option "Equals...." 
and use the date picker and select for 6 April 2022, 
it returns nothing as seen in the image below:

[image]

If I choose the "Before.. / After... / Between..." from the menu option 
and use the date picker (or just write 6-apr-22 in the input box), it filter the date as expected.

My question:

1. Is there any setting which I should change in order that the date picker for the "Equals..." in the Date Filter menu option can work properly ?
2. if I don't use the date picker, how should I type the date in the input box for the "Equals" ? I've tried 04/06/2022  .... 06/04/2022 ... 6-April-2022 .... 2022-04-06 .... 2022/06/04 ... April-6-2022, but also returns nothing.

FYI, the date setting in my computer is set to dd-mmm-yy 
and the date column (TGL) on the worksheet is date formatted (dd-mmm-yy),
while in the formula box it show dd-mm-yy for the cell value.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

UPDATE:
Just now I've tried by making a pivot table and use that date column as the data source.

[image]

Weird, in the pivot table I can filter the date with "Equal" and date picker.

Here is the link for the file :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12KcEpDkazHzZPP2lM-KJpJO9Qp25NE6g/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112918519247102666618&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Make sure of the contents of the cells you are checking.

Comment: What is the real value of the cell that holds `6-4-22`? I mean the value you see in the formula bar, not the one you see in the cell. What if you do that cell+1? Could it be that maybe you don't have just a date (an integer value) but a date **and** a time? So when you do `equals=6-4-22` Excel searchs for **exactly** `6-4-22 00:00:00` and if you have something like `6-4-22 03:26:45` it would not work (but it would with after and before!). And times don't appear in the date picker, just the date.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns,, the value in the formula bar is : 06-04-22. There is not time, just date month and year. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @karma can you share a copy of the file?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, yes I can... but I wonder is it allowed to share a file from Google Drive ? Or maybe in this site there is a way to upload the file ?

Comment: Edit your post and add the link to Gdrive

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, Done. At the very bottom of my question. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @SolarMike, the contents of the cell is like this if seen in the formula box : 06-04-22. As seen in my update, the weird thing, when I try it with the pivot table, it works. I make a pivot table, and have that date column as the data source. Then in the pivot table I can filter it with "Equal" either using the date picker or just type 6 apr 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the format of cells (you are using a custom one instead the default date one). If you change the format to defaul date one it will work:

[image]

Anyways if you need to filter using this custom format, you can use the option equal using **exactly** what you see in the cell `06-abr-22` Any other option won't work

[image]

Comment: Wow.... I never know about that, Foxfire. Thank you very much for your help answer and your explanation. Really appreciate your time to make the animation so I can understand it much better.

Comment: @karma Thanks to you for posting this. I've been making some tests on Excel and it looks like the option "Equal" in filters work with what you see in the cell, but not the real value. But options like "Equal or higher" work with the value itself, not what you see in the cell. Pretty curious to be honest